# compare 2 lists of integers

Tags: python, string, comparison

I have 2 txt files like this:

```
fileA:      fileB:
0           0   
5           0 
0           80
20          10 
600         34
```

I need to compare the numbers in these 2 lists respecting the position in the list. I need to generate an output file with the comparison for each of the lines like:

```
Output:
E
A
B
A
A
```

I have tried something like:

```
lineA = [lineb.rstrip('\n') for lineb in open("fileA.txt")]
lineB = [lineb.rstrip('\n') for lineb in open("fileB.txt")]
for i in lineA:
    for u in lineB:
        if lineA[i] > lineB[i]:
           print("A")
        elif lineA[i] < lineB[i]:
           print("B")
        elif lineA[i] == lineB[i]:
           print("E")
```

but the loop is not able to work properly.
I've tried also to convert first the list in integers ( in case they are not recognized ad int) like:

```
for w in range(0, len(lineA)):
    lineA[w] = int(lineA[w])
    print(str(lineA))
```

BUT I CAN'T SOLVE THE PROBLEM...

Comment: Use the `zip` function loop over two lists in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` to loop through the two lists in parallel:

```
# use `with` to automatically close the files after reading
with open("fileA.txt") as file_a, open("fileB.txt") as file_b:
    # use `int` in the list comprehension
    # and, use `.rstrip()` if you just want to remove whitespace
    lineA = [int(line.rstrip()) for line in file_a]
    lineB = [int(line.rstrip()) for line in file_b]

for i, u in zip(lineA, lineB):
    if i > u:
       print("A")
    elif i < u:
       print("B")
    else:
       print("E")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate both lists in parallel:

```py
lineA = [lineb.rstrip('\n') for lineb in open("fileA.txt")]
lineB = [lineb.rstrip('\n') for lineb in open("fileB.txt")]
for a, b in zip(lineA, lineB):
    if a > b:
       print("A")
    elif a < b:
       print("B")
    elif a == b:
       print("E")
```

You could also avoid one comparison since there are three cases when comparing two numbers `a` and `b`:

- `a` greater than `b`
- `a` less than `b`
- `a` equal to `b`

```py
lineA = [lineb.rstrip('\n') for lineb in open("fileA.txt")]
lineB = [lineb.rstrip('\n') for lineb in open("fileB.txt")]
for a, b in zip(lineA, lineB):
    if a > b:
       print("A")
    elif a < b:
       print("B")
    else:
       print("E")
```

Also consider using `with` to open your files as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `zip` to compare each number to eachother, and `map` `int` to each file:

```
with open("fileA.txt") as file_a, open("fileB.txt") as file_b:
    for a, b in zip(file_a, file_b):
        a, b = map(int, (a, b))
        if a > b:
            print("A")
        elif a < b:
            print("B")
        else:
            print("E")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map` with `zip`:

```
def compare(z):
    a, b = z

    if a == b:
        return 'E'

    if a > b:
        return 'A'

    return 'B'

with open("fileA.txt") as file_a, open("fileB.txt") as file_b:
    a_nums = map(int, map(str.rstrip, file_a.readlines()))
    b_nums = map(int, map(str.rstrip, file_b.readlines()))


    for greater in map(compare, zip(a_nums, b_nums)):
        print(greater)
```

output:

```
E
A
B
A
A
```

for writing to your output file you can use:

```
with open("fileA.txt") as file_a, open("fileB.txt") as file_b, open("output.txt", 'w') as output:
    a_nums = map(int, map(str.rstrip, file_a.readlines()))
    b_nums = map(int, map(str.rstrip, file_b.readlines()))

    for greater in map(compare, zip(a_nums, b_nums)):
        print(greater, file=output)
```